# Linux SMB share - how to give access to Windows local system account?

Tags: linux, windows, samba, network-share

I have a SMB share on a Linux host. To grant remote access to the share for a Windows user, one must create a new SMB user which has the same username, and same password as the Windows account.

i.e. to give access to Windows user `winhost\calvin` I would run `smbpasswd -a calvin`, and use the same password that `winhost\calvin` uses. Then I would update smb.conf to something like

```
[myshare]
path = /home/lincoln/myshare
valid users = lincoln, calvin
read only = no
```

Once this is in place, `calvin` can now see the share from Windows via UNC path `\\<ip addr>\myshare`

This works fine for named user accounts, but **I can't figure out how to grant access to a Windows "local system" account, i.e. a machine account.**

I have tried creating SMB users with names like `WINHOST` and `WINHOST$` with a blank password (local system accounts don't have passwords), but this doesn't seem to work.

When I try to access the share using the system account (via `dir \\<ip addr>\myshare`) I get the error "The specified server cannot perform the requested operation".

**What are the details of the SMB account and config that can make this happen?**

I do not want to make the share public - this seems to be the only workaround I can find so far.

Comment: what are you trying to do? I'm guessing you want to access the share using a scheduled task; if that is the case, you can easily write  script and map the share under another security context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not using a domain, the LocalSystem account can access network resources only [with anonymous credential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684188(VS.85).aspx). In other words, it will *not* present named credential to the remote samba server.

Comment: I see - so it is not possible to assign a SMB username or password that maps to a localsystem account. Thus making the share public is the only way to allow access.